# How to perform CRUD operations on list observable using async pipe in Angular?

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

So far in my Angular apps, i've got used to iterating list with `ngFor` directive without using `async` pipe. But today i've learned about `async` pipe and tried implementing them.

So here's on my a sample component template:

```
<ng-container *ngIf="todos$ | asyc as todos">
  <div *ngFor="let todo of todos">{{ todo.content }}</div>
</ng-container>
```

And on sample component class`

```
this.todos$ = this.todoService.getAllTodos();
```

What i'm trying to figure out is how to add, edit or delete operations on the `todos$` observable.

Comment: I'm not following you... how are used to do it (the fact the you have an `async` should not affect the way you update it) before? If you are asking how to update the list after a database operation, for example, your observable (`todo$`) must reemit it. In this case, it depends on how did you get `todo$` in the first place (from a database using `HttpClient`, or from a `Subject`)

Comment: @jpavel its from a database call using `HttpClient`

Answer (score 0):

First of all `httpClient`'s requests are self completing, which means that after the request has completed it can not emit any new value.

The solution is to use a separate Observable or Subject. In this case a good candidate would `BehaviourSubject`.

First you define

```
this.todos$ = new BehaviourSubject(null);
```

Note that `null` is the default value of `todos$`. You can pass an empty array to get rid of `*ngIf`.

Then after the request is completed emit the response:

```
this.todoService.getAllTodos()
  .subscribe(response => {
    this.todos$.next(response);
  });
```

In the future if you want to change the data, you can get the current value (from the BehaviourSubject), transform it and reemit, for example adding an item would be:

```
this.todos$.next([newItem, ...this.todos$.value]);
```

Comment: Thanks, just tried it and it worked. Isn't too much of a work when manipulating lists using `async` pipe rather than subscribing inside the component class and just make sure to unsubscribe the observable?

Comment: If your question is about the execution time, I believe there is no difference as in both cases you have an observable and a subscription.
In contrast, angular does the dirty work of unsubscribing in async pipe, so I personally prefer using async pipe whenever it makes it easier.
But you should be careful not to overuse as it may cause performance issues.